# How can I extract certain strings with Xpath

Tags: xpath

```
<span>1 Bedroom, 1 Bath</span>
```

Hi
I am new in Xpath. And my English is not very well, but I'll try. I need to extract with Xpath only '1 Bedroom' and '1 Bath'. How can I do this?
Thank you a lot

Comment: '<span>1 Bedroom, 1 Bath</span>'

Answer (score 0):

You can use `substring-after()` and `substring-before()`:

```
substring-before(span, ',')

substring-after(span, ', ')
```